# Automatic makefile/header file generator

Tags: makefile, automation, header-files

Is there a way, when a create a makefile or a header to just have a template that I've made. Like when i create a .h file it puts automatically the:

#ifndef NAME_OF_FILE_H

#define NAME_OF_FILE_H

#endif

And with the makefile just put the cc and ccflags.

I've looked everywhere but i cant find this info, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

It would be a (potential) feature of the editor you use.  vim refers to this feature as snippets, and there are a number of plugins like [SnipMate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) and [UltiSnips](https://github.com/sirver/UltiSnips) that implements it.